# solving for unknown 2d rotation + translation

Tags: calibration, mapping

This is a continuation of the question I asked [here](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/19023/building-a-grid-map-from-gps-trajectory-poses). I thought I'll ask a more concrete question. So far, this is what I have done to transform from a feature point detected by camera sensor in to a map point, where feature is a 2d homogenous vector.

```
map_point = T_world_origin.inverse() * T_world_gps * T_gps_camera * feature_point
```

There is significant ghosting on the map, as shown below, and I suspected that `T_gps_camera` is inaccurate. I wish to solve for T_gps_camera (3x3 homogoenous matrix) analytically, and I arrive at the equation below,

```
M * T_world_origin.inverse() * T_world_gps_t * T_gps_camera * feature_point = T_world_origin.inverse() * T_world_gps_t+1 * T_gps_camera * feature_point
```

where M is a 3x3 matrix I have calculated using ICP of the map points at time t and t+1. Following this, how should I use the ICP information I have to solve for T_GPS_camera?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your camera is rigidly mounted to your vehicle, and that the GPS is also rigidly mounted to the vehicle, then there should be a fixed transform between the GPS and camera.

Your `M` matrix is the correction that shifts your data between time steps. This *should* just have to correct some minor white noise, from GPS noise for example. It should be *zero mean*. If there is some fixed offset that you haven't modeled, then you should notice your `M` matrix have some non-zero mean.

I would look carefully at your `M` matrix over time - consider getting the rotation angle from the 2x2 sub-matrix and the x/y offset from the position vector and look at those values, especially as you make turns. As I mentioned in [your other question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/19023/9720), I think you're missing a rotation sensor and that is affecting your data especially on turns.

If I'm correct, you should see zero-mean noise during straight sections and then some non-zero mean during turns. Once you get the rotation-induced issues worked out (adding a compass, IMU, etc.), then you should go back to seeing zero-mean rotations and offsets during *all* maneuvers.

If you're seeing some non-zero means during straight sections, then I would take those average values and update your GPS-camera offset accordingly. You *could* do this on the fly, by using a low-pass filter to update the GPS-camera transform, but I worry that the turns aren't correct at the moment and it shouldn't be necessary because again everything is fixed.

So, tl;dr - use the mean of your `M` matrix when you're getting good data to adjust your uncertain transform. Monitor the mean of the `M` matrix to ensure all your data is being transformed well with your known transforms.